# Android animation is working but not as expected. Instead of sliding in down, it just fade in

Tags: android

The code below is a part of an existing library:

```
public class ActivitySample extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imvLogo;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user);
        imvLogo = findViewById(R.id.imvLogo);
        
        Render render = new Render(this);
        render.setAnimation(Slide.InDown(imvLogo));
        render.setDuration(5000);
        render.start();
    }
    
}

public class Render {
    private long duration = 1000;
    private Context cx;
    private AnimatorSet animatorSet;

    // Render render = new Render(this)
    public Render  (Context cx) {
        this.cx = cx;
    }

    // render.setAnimation(Bounce.In(textView))
    public void setAnimation (AnimatorSet animationSet) {
        this.animatorSet = animationSet;
    }

    // render.start()
    public void start() {
        animatorSet.setDuration(duration);
        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        animatorSet.start();
    }

    // render.setDuration(2000)
    public void setDuration(long duration){
        this.duration = duration;
    }

}

public class Slide {
    public static AnimatorSet InDown(View view) {
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        int distance = view.getTop() + view.getHeight();

        ObjectAnimator object1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,"alpha", 0, 1);
        ObjectAnimator object2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,"translationY", - distance, 0);

        animatorSet.playTogether(object1, object2);
        return animatorSet;
    }
}
```

I have an animation code set to just slide down an ImageView. The weird thing is before, the animation is working properly but now it is working but instead of sliding down while fading in, it just fade in and that's it.

I tried clearing the cache and restart the Android Studio but still the same. I tried coding the animation in XML and call it in the activity and it is working properly. But I really want to implement the code I provided since I find it more flexible. Please help me with it. Please excuse if you find unrelated errors from the code I provided. I just re-write and copy/paste it from scratch since the actual file is quite populated.